# What is the public address of installed app?

Tags: juju

I've installed [Discourse](http://jujucharms.com/~marcoceppi/precise/discourse), wordpress, etc by juju. The below show the result for Discourse. how can I see it in my browser? what's the address?

`juju status`

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.17.5.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: saucy
      "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.17.5.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.3
    instance-id: onrea-local-machine-1
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64
  "2":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.17.5.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.121
    instance-id: onrea-local-machine-2
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64
services:
  discourse:
    charm: local:precise/discourse-0
    exposed: true
    relations:
      db:
      - postgresql
      discourse:
      - discourse
    units:
      discourse/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.17.5.1
        machine: "1"
        public-address: 10.0.3.3
  postgresql:
    charm: cs:precise/postgresql-62
    exposed: false
    relations:
      db-admin:
      - discourse
      replication:
      - postgresql
    units:
      postgresql/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.17.5.1
        machine: "2"
        open-ports:
    - 5432/tcp
    public-address: 10.0.3.121
```

Comment: Onrea, I don't see a open-ports: 80  on your discourse unit. Did the installation encounter any errors during deployment that were "resolved" with juju resolved discourse/0?

Comment: I had not any error when installing Discourse! `juju resolved discourse/0` => No Error, No Output! | I destroyed it and tried for wordpress, here is the result for juju status`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7131754/ AND the command `juju resolved wordpress/0` does not have any error! I

Answer (score 3):

The `public-address` is the address assigned to the machine so in the case of discourse here it would be `public-address: 10.0.3.3`

Comment: It can not run Discourse in firefox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Qod.png

Comment: @onrea Do you have port forwarding enabled so the router forwards your request over the right port? Also try the local address: `<local-adress>:<port-number>`. If I recall, Discourse uses port 3000. You can get the local address from `ifconfig`.

Comment: @Seth, nope. Indeed, I don't know what is "port forwarding".

Answer (score 1):

To build off of Hatch's answer, the address of the Discourse unit is the public-address line in the status display.

There are a few things at play here that can cause a problem with this particular installation.

1) Is your LAN using the same IP Scheme as whats being used in the LXC Container? eg: `10.0.3.x` on your home lan, you may be having an ip collision with another PC. Which would prevent you from being able to access this unit

2) Is your bridge device up? When you run ifconfig do you see lxcbr0 in the output?

3) Are you able to reach the machine with juju ssh? `juju ssh discourse/0` (this will tell you network connectivity is present to the unit, and you can move on to the service level of debugging)

4) Is Apache/NGINX running on the host? If so, is it started and do the logs give you any output? Check in /var/log/nginx/

5) Can you connect to the Discourse service running on port 3000 directly? If you can, there is a problem with NGINX's reverse proxy to Discourse

6) Check that your UFW firewall rulesets are not to blame here. Temporarily bring down your UFW firewall (if any is present) using ufw disable, and try connecting again.

Comment: 1. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7145199 || 2. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7131793 || 3. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7131801 || 4. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7131807 || 5. http://localhost:3000 => Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3000 || 6. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7145202/

Comment: you have 2 services with hook errors in your last paste

Comment: Here's a new attempt: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7149890/ | Isn't it related to my OS version: 13.10?